# Django SortedManyToManyField perform reorder

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, m2m

I have the following two models where a Product may have many categories and a Category may have many Products associated with it:

```
from sortedm2m.fields import SortedManyToManyField


class Product(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    is_visible = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    categories = SortedManyToManyField(to=Category, blank=True, related_name="product_items")
    number = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True, null=True)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    related_product_items = models.ManyToManyField(to="self", blank=True)


class Category(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    parent = models.ForeignKey(
        to="self", on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True, related_name="subcategories",
    )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    is_visible = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

My ProductOrderingSerializer serializer:

```
class ProductOrderingSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    products = serializers.ListSerializer(child=serializers.UUIDField(), required=True)
    category = serializers.UUIDField(required=True)
```

My view:

```
class ProductViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    @transaction.atomic
    @action(methods=["put"], detail=False)
    def order(self, request):
        """
        this end point receives list of ids and changes order of products per 
        category
        # products = [2, 8, 4, 22]
        # category = 'xyz'
        """
        serializer = ProductOrderingSerializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        queryset = self.queryset.filter(id__in=serializer.validated_data["products"])
        category = serializer.validated_data["category"]
        for index, product_id in enumerate(serializer.validated_data["products"]):
            # how to perform product ordering per the submitted category?
            pass
        self.action = "list"
        return self.list(request=request)
```

The order of products is in regard to the category they are in. For example if we have product `p1`, and `p2` in categories `x` and `y`, as in the following:

```
category x:
    p1,
    p2

category y:
    p1,
    p2
```

and I perform a request as such:

```
products [p2, p1]
category = 'x'
```

The order becomes

```
category x:
    p2,
    p1

category y:
    p1,
    p2
```

Only the order of products in the `x category` is updated, so `product p1` for example still preserves the order of index[0] at `category y`, while it is been updated in the called category.

I have been trying to find a solution for the last couple days, but nothing that would work as intended. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

## The following concept will be work for you

##### 1. get the category and get all related products to save them in the old sequence (you must load it in memory not leave it as a query )

##### 2. clear all related m2m by using `category.product_items.clear()`

##### 3. add the new order you want by using `category.product_items.add(your_product)`

##### 4. add the old remaining in old sequence from #1(add them all if it is found it will be added again)